# Use lapply to change all elements of a certain value to another value, on a colum by column basis in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, lapply

For each column in a data frame, I want to replace all non-zero values with the column number.
ie, if I have a data frame like:

```
> df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.1), nrow = 4, ncol = 3))
> df1
   V1  V2  V3
1 0.0 0.0 0.0
2 0.1 0.1 0.1
3 0.0 0.0 0.0
4 0.1 0.1 0.1
```

I want to change it to:

```
>df2
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  0  0  
2  1  2  3
3  0  0  0
4  1  2  3
```

I've tried multiple variations on the following without success - I just can't wrap my head around what the the function in a lapply call refers to.

```
  counter <- 0
  lapply(df1, function(x){
    df1[,x][df1[,x]>0] <- counter
    counter <<- counter+1
  })

  counter <- 0
  lapply(df1, function(x){
    x[][x[]>0] <- counter
    counter <<- counter+1
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in a more compact way

```
df1[] <-  col(df1) * !!df1
```

-output

```
df1
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  0  0  0
#2  1  2  3
#3  0  0  0
#4  1  2  3
```

---

Convert the 'df1' to a logical matrix i.e. TRUE for non- zero values and FALSE for zero (`!!df1`) and multiply with column index (`col(df1)`) so that any value that is FALSE -> 0, and those that are TRUE -> 1, returns the column index

---

Or another option in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ~  match(cur_column(), names(df1)) * (. != 0)))
```

Comment: thanks so much - definitely elegant, will use this and keep my new lapply knowledge from @gregorthomas in my back pocket.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `lapply` and have access to column numbers, iterate over the column numbers:

```
df1[] = lapply(seq_along(df1), function(i) {
  replace(df1[[i]], df1[[i]] != 0, i)
})

df1
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  0  0  0
# 2  1  2  3
# 3  0  0  0
# 4  1  2  3
```

When modifying columns in-place with `lapply`, remember that assignment has to take place *outside* the `lapply` call. Using brackets like `data[] = lapply(...)` is a useful trick so that the `list` returned by `lapply` gets interpreted as columns of the data frame.

Comment: Thanks! I had also tried iterating over column numbers to no avail - but I see now that my main issue was that I was referring to the column indices in the function as if they were in a df and not in a list.

Comment: You could replace my `df1[[i]]` with `df1[, i]` and get the same result. I just prefer using `[[`  when I know I want a single column. I think your bigger issue was trying to assign to `df1` inside `lapply`, whereas the main assignment needs to be of the `lapply` result.